# How to wait NSTask to finish in async block

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstask

```
 NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Did fail with error %@" , [error localizedDescription]);
            fail();
            return ;
        }
        else
        {
        }
```

I use `dataTaskWithRequest` to send async http request and in the completion block, i want to run a `python script`.

```
 NSTask * task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:kPythonPath];
    [task setArguments:@[self.scriptFileFullPath,outputFile]];
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkPythonTaskStatus:) name:NSTaskDidTerminateNotification object:task];
```

the `python` task may take a long time so i should wait for its completion. But the `NSTaskDidTerminateNotification` will not be sent since the `NSTask` is running in a separate thread. Anyone know how to wait for `NSTask` to finish in this condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSTask` has a property `terminationHandler`.

> The completion block is invoked when the task has completed. The task
>   object is passed to the block to allow access to the task parameters,
>   for example to determine if the task completed successfully.

---

```
NSTask * task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath = kPythonPath;
task.arguments = @[self.scriptFileFullPath, outputFile];
task.terminationHandler = ^(NSTask *task){
 // do things after completion
};
[task launch];
```